# view one particular column data in to several columns by filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, group-by

I have a Table with a column which contains `Leave` types (`Annual`, `Casual`, `Medical`, etc.).

Now I need to split it to several columns by separate according to the Leave types `Annual Leave`, `Casual Leave`, `Medical Leave`, etc.

Table `LeaveAccount`

```
LeaveAccountID, 
LeaveTypeID, 
EmployeeID, 
AccountingYearID, 
TotalLeaves, 
LeavesTaken
```

Table `LeaveType`

```
LeaveTypeID,
LeaveTypeName
```

My Query [which gives an infinite loop] is:

[FullName, EmplyeeID, AnnualLeave, ShortLeave, Medical Leave]

```
SELECT
    e.FullName
  , e.EmployeeId
  , a.TotalLeaves as AnnualLeave
  , b.TotalLeaves as shortleave
  , c.TotalLeaves as MedicalLeave
FROM
    LeaveAccount a
  , Employee e
  , LeaveAccount b
  , LeaveAccount c
WHERE
      (a.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId) 
  and (
            (a.LeaveTypeId = 0) 
        and (b.LeaveTypeId = 20)
        and (c.LeaveTypeId = 1)
      )
```

Do I need to go for Dynamic SQL? How can split I like this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to split your table?

When you can create VIEWS of your table, each view will contains one column:

```
CREATE VIEW 
   Annual_Leave
AS 
SELECT 
   Annual
FROM 
   Leave types;
```

You do the same the the remaining columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SubSelects:

```
SELECT
    e.FullName
  , e.EmployeeId
  , (SELECT SUM(a.TotalLeaves) FROM LeaveAccount a WHERE a.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId AND a.LeaveTypeId = 0) AS "AnnualLeave"
  , (SELECT SUM(b.TotalLeaves) FROM LeaveAccount b WHERE b.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId AND b.LeaveTypeId = 20) AS "ShortLeave"
  , (SELECT SUM(c.TotalLeaves) FROM LeaveAccount c WHERE c.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId AND c.LeaveTypeId = 1) AS "MedicalLeave"
FROM
  Employee e
```

Another solution would be grouping:

```
SELECT
    e.FullName
  , e.EmployeeId
  , SUM(a.TotalLeaves) AS "AnnualLeave"
  , SUM(b.TotalLeaves) AS "ShortLeave"
  , SUM(c.TotalLeaves) AS "MedicalLeave"
FROM
  Employee e
INNER JOIN
  LeaveAccount a
ON
      a.EmployeeId  = e.EmployeeId
  AND a.LeaveTypeId = 0
INNER JOIN
  LeaveAccount b
ON
      b.EmployeeId  = e.EmployeeId
  AND b.LeaveTypeId = 20
INNER JOIN
  LeaveAccount c
ON
      c.EmployeeId  = e.EmployeeId
  AND c.LeaveTypeId = 1
GROUP BY
    e.FullName
  , e.EmployeeId
```

**Edit:** You might have to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` here, depending you your data.